# Java Swing: Enabling/Disabling specific type of components

Tags: java, forms, swing

I need to enable/disable some components inside a JFrame. But i only want to disable these types:

```
JTextField
JButton
JComboBox
```

Is there any simple example about doing that kind of things in java?

Comment: safest could be loop/iterating inside container

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through all the components of the JFrame, including components inside other components, and do an instanceof check to see if it's one of the types you want to disable, if so, disable the component.

As an example on how to do this, one could enable or disable all JButtons with the following function :

```
public void flipEnabledOnAllButtons(boolean enabled, Container rootContainerToSearch)
{    
    for (Component c : rootContainerToSearch.getComponents())    
    {    
        if (c instanceof Container)    
        {    
            flipEnabledOnAllButtons(enabled, (Container)c);    
        }    

        if (c instanceof JButton)    
        {    
            c.setEnabled(enabled);    
        }      
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give me a little example? I don't know how to get component type.

Comment: Sure, an example to disable/enable all JButtons:

    public void flipEnabledOnAllButtons(boolean enabled, Container rootContainerToSearch)
    {    
        for (Component c : rootContainerToSearch.getComponents())    
        {    
            if (c instanceof Container)    
            {    
                disableAllButtons((Container)c);    
            }    
            else    
            {    
                if (c instanceof JButton)    
                {    
                    c.setEnabled(enabled);    
                }    
            }    
        }
    }

Comment: If you edit your answer and put these codes to there, it would be very useful for everyone :)

Comment: Alright, I modified the answer to include the example for JButtons.

Comment: I'm sending "this" to the function but it couldn't find .

Comment: Did you pass false as well? And is this a JFrame or some other root container in your project?

Comment: Yes, this is a jframe. My components are set as not enabled. So i need to set true to see them enabled.

Comment: Sorry, code had a bug in it, JButton is a container so we'd never get into that else statement. Changed the answer to have correct code. Make sure you call this on the EDT too.

Comment: Thanks but why in EDT? I have an if else clause to get this work. It works well.

Comment: Swing classes are not thread safe, so to get around this Swing practices thread confinement with how it wishes to modify all state on the EDT. The idea is if the EDT is the only thread that looks at the state and modifies it, then no threading issues should appear (as long as your application code continues this practice).

Answer (score 1):

Check out Darryl's [Swing Utils](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/13/swing-utils/). You can use the class to get a List of components of a specific class. Then you iterate through the list to do your processing.

Ro example to get al the combo box compnents you could uee:

```
List<JComboBox> components = SwingUtils.getDescendantsOfType(JComboBox.class, frame.getContentPane(), true);
```